# TFS2012: Add label at a specific changeset in version control?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I want to add a label to a specific changeset in my version control of TFS2012.
I right clicked at the branch -> Advanced -> Apply Label. I selected a specific changeset in the past and created the label.
But all labels I created are bound to the first changeset in that branch and not to the one I entered in the labels dialog.

Is this a bug? Or how can I add a label to a specific changeset?

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want to do this? You can use a changeset number just as well as a label to identify a particular point in version history.

Comment: I mark all changesets we published as a release or a hotfix that way. Thus, we can restore the code for a specific release very fast.

Comment: @Konrad, Did you find a better solution to it?

Comment: @kamalpreet No idea. didn't use labels in TFS VC for about 5 years ... and that's a long time for TFS releases ;-)

Comment: Any suggestions for how to tag a changeset?
Basically I'm looking for a way to know which changesets were published to production.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Labels will label all files/folders in the directory at the revision they were for that specific changeset.

This means that if you right click the containing folder and view labels it will look like it put the label on the first changeset of the branch (as the main folder likely hasn't changed since the first changeset).

If you right click in source control explorer and select -> find -> find by label, then select your label and click edit, you'll see a list of all files in the label and the changeset of when they last changed prior to the label changeset.

Long story short, it's not a bug, it's just confusing.

Comment: So if I set a label to a specific changeset, how do I see which changeset I set this label to? And is there a way to see the changeset between labels? Without this information, it seems that labels are less useful.

Answer (score -3):

In the visual studio , File -> Source control -> Advanced -> apply lable 
Provide the project/source path in the window and click create. Ofcourse you can find your label in the source control history. After each live release this is good practice to label your solution guys.